# Is there a way to call a function when the interface rotates in Iphone?

Tags: iphone

When my interface rotates i want to call certain functions. How can I do these actions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do,

Implement [some of these methods](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW58) in your active view controller class:

- `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
- `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`
- `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`

Or [some of these methods](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW3) in your app delegate:

- `-application:willChangeStatusBarOrientation:duration:`
- `-application:didChangeStatusBarOrientation:`

Or listen to [some of these local notifications](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4):

- UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
- UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification
- UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
- UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
      selector:@selector(yourMethod:)
      name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```