# Handle device rotation for "More" UINavigationController in UITabBarController.moreNavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app which has to work in both portrait and landscape more and the UITabBar should adjust to current orientation (it has custom background and selected items). So, for the rest of views I just override the `- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` method and it works perfectly.

How would I do that for the `.moreNavigationController` of `UITabBarController` ? I've tried adding an observer (the selector is in extension of UITabBarController):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(didRotate:)
name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
object:self.moreNavigationController];
```

but it never get called.
Am I missing something or what would be the best way to handle this situation ?

**Solution**: somewhy `UIDeviceOrientation` is not firing correctly, so better to use `statusBarOrientation`, works as a charm.

the final code which work is this:
in main `UITabBarController`, `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

the `didRotate` selector method:

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        // Portrait
    } else {
        // Landscape
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering your `UITabBarController` for a notification which never gets posted. Take a look at the documentation [NSNotificationCenter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the `addObserver:selector:name:object` method

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```

> **`notificationSender`:**
>   The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.
>   If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

so, if you specify the `. moreNavigationController` as the sender, you wont get those notifications, because it never posts such ones. Instead pass `nil` to ignore the sender and listen to the status bar change regardless of who sent it.

By the way, in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652828/719656) is a summary of how you can react to orientation change.

And at last. If it still doesn't work, you can try this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: please check my final solution for the correct answer. Yours made me thing and allowed to resolve the issue, so the bounty is yours. :) Thanks.

Comment: @whiteagle When using the device orientation notification, you can get the orientation like this: [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]. Maybe that's why it didn't work for you. Otherwise your solution looks good. Glad to be of help :)

Comment: the device orientation wasn't even called, donno why. :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you forgot to post notification, which will call you own notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:self];
```

or if you dont wont to send anything just set object as nil:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: How will I post a notification from the controller I have no access to ?

Comment: `postNotificationName:` is to fire a notification manually, as by documentation:
_Creates a notification with a given name and sender and posts it to the receiver._
the `.moreNavigationController` is read-only property, I can't override it with my own controller nor extend any implementation. So, where you suggest to fire the notification from ? The rotation event is generated by the system and I am looking for some way to handle it, not to generate it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement the same is first addObserver and then remove observer to avoid the crash:-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                 name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}

//Now Remove Observer
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self @"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
}
```